# hide extensions of the pages with web.config

Tags: iis, url, web-config, url-rewriting

How do I hide the extensions of the pages?

Example ... access as is the normal asp page, but I would like to access the page or pages as ... without. asp

In my case I want it in web.config

Thanks!

Comment: So, are you running this on IIS or on Apache?  mod_rewrite is an Apache thing, but web.config typically is for web applications in IIS.

Comment: Retagged to get attention of people with IIS experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS URL Rewrite to do that, you can download it from: http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

After that you can easily write rules to rewrite the path to match anything you want, including removing file extensions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If hiding dynamic page you should have in IIS > Handler Mappings a line with ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit

If static page, IIS has a bug for static files and you need to apply a hotfix (if not applied yet)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2646735

after that you need to add to your Web.Config system.webServer section

Answer (score -2):

you can modify the web.config file so the url only shows the directory

[Hide webpage name](http://symplexsystems.com/blog/post/2011/07/27/URL-Rewriting-without-configuring-IIS-Hide-web-page-name-or-extension.aspx)